# how to return a specific value if a substring (i.e., a word) is found in a cell which contains text in EXCEL

Tags: excel, string, indexing, excel-formula, partial-matches

I have the following two tables in EXCEL. I want to return the specific value (in the cells highlighted in yellow) from the Table 2. Table 2 has eight variables (i.e. substrings) horizontally and some other variables in Column H. I tried to use `SEARCH` with `INDEX` and `MATCH` with wildcards to return the values when the specific substring appears in the text (either at the beginning of the sentence or in between) from the column B called "Variable" of Table 1, but it did not work.

[image]

Table1

| Variable | aaaa | bbbb | cccc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| dff dfkjdfj Copper | 1 | 14 | 27 |
| jdfjfd Steel & Iron dfff | 2 | 15 | 28 |
| sddsd Aluminium | 3 | 16 | 29 |
| sdsdsd Zinc | 5 | 18 | 31 |
| dfdf Tin | 6 | 19 | 32 |
| dfdfd Nickel jkdhffdhdf | 7 | 20 | 33 |

Table2

|  | Copper | Steel & Iron | Aluminium | Lead | Zinc | Tin | Nickel | Tantalum | lolybdenul | Wolfram | Silver | Gold | Platinum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aaaa | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 |
| bbbb | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 | 21 | 22 | 23 | 24 | 25 | 26 |
| cccc | 27 | 28 | 29 | 30 | 31 | 32 | 33 | 34 | 35 | 36 | 37 | 38 | 39 |
| dddd | 40 | 41 | 42 | 43 | 44 | 45 | 46 | 47 | 48 | 49 | 50 | 51 | 52 |

Comment: Please try using **[MarkdownTableGenerator](https://tabletomarkdown.com/convert-spreadsheet-to-markdown/)** it helps to copy the data easily and to provide solutions

Answer (score 3):

You could try using the formula as shown in the screenshot:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `C3`

```
=INDEX($I$3:$U$6,MATCH(C$2,$H$3:$H$6,0),MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" "&$I$2:$U$2&" "," "&$B3&" ")),0))
```

---

Another probable alternative could be using `XLOOKUP()` with `COUNTIF()` & `FILTER()` Function.

Since the first alternative is an `array` formula, based on your `Excel` version needs to hit  <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> while exiting the **edit mode**, however if you are using **O365** or **Excel 2021** you dont require.

---

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `C3`

```
=XLOOKUP(
    1,
    COUNTIF(
        $B3,
        "*" & $I$2:$U$2 & "*"
    ),
    FILTER(
        $I$3:$U$6,
        C$2 = $H$3:$H$6
    )
)
```

---

Comment: Thank you for your valuable contribution. The first alternative, the `array` did work but the second one, with the `XLOOKUP` did not work.

Comment: @ChrisGila cañ you show how its not working, however you have one alternative already to work with.